# How do I log time consuming operations? (C#)

Tags: c#, performance, timer, xna, slowdown

My game runs a lot of calculations, sometimes the framerate drops without obvious reasons, and I'd like to find out what takes so long to process. How to create a timer (or something) to print out elapsed times for each major operation?

**UPD:** after running the default profiler, I found out that the bottleneck is in my tile array loop. I have about half million tiles and the loop asks for tile's one property, for about 200 tiles per frame. Like so:

```
if (tileArray[tile].this_tile_is_on_screen)
tileArray[tile].Draw();
```

Could this lead to slowdowns when the tileArray is very big? Any advice on how to avoid it?

Comment: Are you looking for something different from [standard profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming))?

Comment: I tried using the profiler and updated post with results.

Comment: I'd like to suggest opening a new question about the _results_ of your profiling; fixing one application is different from learning how to find the slow points in _any_ application. (Any chance you can populate smaller lists of tiles that should be visible or not and remove the 500,000 tile loop each frame?)

Comment: The loop runs about 200 times over a 500,000 tile array, and I'll probably take it to a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a profiler such as the [EQATEC Profiler for .NET](http://www.eqatec.com/tools/profiler/), or the one built into the Premium and Ultimate versions of [Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx).

If you are already using a logging framework, such as log4Net, you can sprinkle sections of code with logging and turn up the logging verbosity.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.aspx) class from [Diagnostic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15t15zda.aspx) namespace for timer.
And [WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx) function from [Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x31ezs1.aspx) class for print out to print out elapsed times.